# How to increase Google Geocoding API

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

we will have ~300K business address information daily(without geocodes),

for which we are supposed to do some analysis (geocodes are required for us, we are using google geocoding API for this)

but the limit are : 2,500 requests per 24 hour period

how can i increase these limits ?

If Google Maps for Business license is the only solution (100,000 requests per 24 hour period), 
can we take licence only for geocoding service ?

please suggest

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question but you could use a different address source, for example OpenStreetMap.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you could hire some (30) developers with API credentials to borrow their keys for this task?

Comment: how would 75000 requests help with 300000 needed? i lol'd while reading your answer, though ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you can somehow build the logic of your app so that the requests are being sent from the client side and on a per-user basis, you should be fine.

From [Geocoding Strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat):

> As geocoding limits are per user session, there is no risk that your application will reach a global limit as your userbase grows. Client-side geocoding will not face a quota limit unless you perform a batch of geocoding requests within a user session. Therefore, running client-side geocoding, you generally don't have to worry about your quota.

Comment: but my case is Server-Side Geocoding

Comment: Then it looks like your only choice is to buy the license unless you go with other geocoding APIs but AFAIK all the others also impose a pretty low limit for the number of requests you can make.

Comment: @NimaVaziri This is not true for OpenStreetMap where you can host all the required data yourself.

Comment: Then OpenStreetMap _might_ be an alternative for OP though I wasn't considering that since the question implied retrieving data from an external source and not from local host.